# How to organize XCode project structure with library, unit tests and iOS app?

Tags: xcode

I'd like to have code with XC tests (the tests are launched on Mac) and iOS app that uses that code. I'm having:

1. One workspace
2. Two projects

   2.1. Project 1: Mac OS static library (code + tests to run on Mac)

   2.2. Project 2: iOS app that uses Project 1 code

The problem is that library is build for x86_64 platform and iOS app fails to link as it's built for i386 platform (to run in iOS simulator):

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file
> /Users/asmirnov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFileSystem-colswwvuefyumkclybhsyoymndun/Build/Products/Debug/libFileSystem.a
>
> ...
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can i do it?

PS. Should i use "iOS static library" Project type instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it for me case and probably it can be useful for others.

Create 2 targets instead of default 1 target (and 2 products) for library - both Mac OS (to be used for unit tests on dev machine) and iOS (to be used in iOS app). See `Base SDK` in target build settings.